# python tkinter scrollbar and text widget issues

Tags: python, text, scrollbar, tkinter

I'm trying to get two text boxes that each have scrollbars. When I try this however:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

s_start = Scrollbar(root)
t_start = Text(root, width=50, height=10)

t_start.focus_set()

s_start.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
t_start.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

s_start.config(command=t_start.yview)
t_start.config(yscrollcommand=s_start.set)

s_end = Scrollbar(root)
t_end = Text(root, width=50, height=10)

t_end.focus_set()

s_end.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
t_end.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

s_end.config(command=t_end.yview)
t_end.config(yscrollcommand=s_end.set)

root.mainloop()
```

This happens:

[image]

In case this isn't clear, those are two separate text boxes, with the right textbox functionally bound to the inner scroll bar, and the left textbox functionally bound to the outer scrollbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use Frames and add the Scrollbars to the Frames instead of to Root.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

left = Frame(root)
right = Frame(root)

t_start = Text(left, width=20)
t_start.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
s_start = Scrollbar(left)
s_start.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
s_start.config(command=t_start.yview)
t_start.config(yscrollcommand=s_start.set)

t_end = Text(right, width=20)
t_end.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
s_end = Scrollbar(right)
s_end.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
s_end.config(command=t_end.yview)
t_end.config(yscrollcommand=s_end.set)

left.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
right.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

root.geometry("500x200")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Two TkInter Text with Scrollbars]

Comment: Perfect. Now how do I give the frames a border and a height?

Comment: I fixed the packing positions.

Comment: Ok thanks, then is it possible to add a border to the boxes even while inactive?