# The horizontal scrollbar didn't work in Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter, scrollbar

I want to create a GUI program base on tkinter. One of the widgets is `Text`. I want to add a horizontal scrollbar in it, but it didn't work.

Where did I make a mistake?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont


class DpWin(object):

    def run(self):
        root=Tk()
        root.geometry('768x612')
        title='dp'
        root.title(title)

        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
        yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        text = Text(root,xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        text.pack()

        xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
        yscrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
        text.insert(END,'a'*999)
        mainloop()

    def start(self):
        self.b_start.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.b_stop.config(state=ACTIVE)

    def stop(self):
        self.b_stop.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.b_start.config(state=ACTIVE)


if __name__=='__main__':
    win=DpWin()
    win.run()
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? (This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6964782/404469)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've modified your code according to [here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm).  There are 2 main differences.

1. I made it so the textbox doesn't wrap.  If you wrap text, there is nothing for the horizontal scrollbar to scroll to.
2. I used the grid geometry manager on a frame to keep the scrollbars and text widgets together.  The advantage to using `.grid` is that you actually get scrollbars which are the correct width/height (something you can't achieve with `pack`).

...

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class DpWin(object):
    def run(self):
        root=Tk()
        root.geometry('768x612')
        title='dp'
        root.title(title)

        f = Frame(root)
        f.pack()

        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(f, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(f)
        yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        text = Text(f, wrap=NONE,
                    xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                    yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        text.grid(row=0, column=0)

        xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
        yscrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
        text.insert(END, 'a'*999)
        mainloop()

    def start(self):
        self.b_start.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.b_stop.config(state=ACTIVE)

    def stop(self):
        self.b_stop.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.b_start.config(state=ACTIVE)

if __name__=='__main__':
    win=DpWin()
    win.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice.It help me ! I lost the "wrap=NONE" when I create the Text.I will learn how to use grid geometry manager.Thank you!

Comment: Sure.  Always happy to help.  Good luck.  (I prefer `grid` to `pack`).  Some think that pack is easier, but I've always thought `grid` to be much more intuitive...

Comment: @mgilson   I faced the same probelm. When using the pack manager, the xscrollbar won't work whatever I did. Even if I commented the yscrollbar code. The Solution you provided above works for grid manager. However, if the code is long and pack manager has been already in use, grid manager is of no help. Using grid manager and pack mangaer causes the code to enter in an infinite negotiation. I hope you post a solution using the pack manager. Still I am stuck with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is one comment regarding making both x and y scrollbars work within the pack framework. Here is a minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import X, Y, BOTTOM, RIGHT, LEFT, Y, HORIZONTAL
class TextExample(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()

        sy = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        sx = tk.Scrollbar(self,  orient=HORIZONTAL)
        editor = tk.Text(self, height=500, width=300, wrap='none')
        sx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        sy.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        editor.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        sy.config(command=editor.yview)
        sx.config(command=editor.xview)
        self.pack()
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x500+0+0")
    app = TextExample(master=root)
    root.mainloop()  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```